# CSS Can't set width and other attributes on form input

Tags: css, reactjs, input

I can't get the width of my input elements to change (using normalize.css, `SASS` and React, not sure if that matters). This is my code:

```
.landing__sign-up-form__input{
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: red;
};
```

I know that this selector is affecting the inputs because they turn red. But they don't change in size or grow any padding. I don't use element id attributes - trying to stick to BEM - so it's not that. 
I also tried using a tag selector just to see if that would work, and tried using `!important` to override anything that might be being set by `normalize.css` or something similar that I don't know of:

```
input {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 4rem;
  padding: .3rem;

  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  outline: none;

  border-radius: .6rem;
};
```

In this one, the `background`turns blue, but `outline`, `padding`, and width don't work (not sure about `border-radius`).

this is one of my inputs in question:

```
    <input
      className = "landing__sign-up-form__input"
      type = "email"
      name = "email"
      placeholder = "bearded_yak101@yaksRus.com"
    />
```

Can anybody tell me what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Normalize.css is tampering with your CSS hierarchy for input. Use the dev tools selector on an input and look at the highest-level element styling on that page. You should see a width set, among other options. You can use the same selector it's using and apply the styling you want in your CSS, forcing the style you want. Alternatively, find where that default value is being applied.

Comment: Set input to `display:inline-block` then give it an explicit width (ex. `width:5rem`)

Comment: @JonnyBeoulve Thanks! This put me on the right track. It wasn't normalize.css but using the dev tools selector helped me find it. I'll be using that lots in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The input needs the attribute `class` not `className`

```css
.landing__sign-up-form__input{
    width: 20rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: red;
};
```

```html
<input
    class = "landing__sign-up-form__input"
    type = "email"
    name = "email"
    placeholder = "some_email@some_domain.com"
/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. In React, you use JSX instead of HTML - they look almost the same but one difference is that you have to use className instead of class. Thanks though

Comment: actually, that's probably my bad since I tagged this question with html, not jsx. Sorry :/

Comment: @DougSauve edit your question and change the tags to the right ones. Will increase chances to get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on React its className or else its just Class

Answer (score 0):

The input element should contain class instead of className.

```
<input
    class = "landing__sign-up-form__input"
    type = "email"
    name = "email"
    placeholder = "some_email@some_domain.com"
/>
```

Comment: If you believe that my answer is good you can upvote it, you don't have to copy/paste it.